# How to plot count of null values for each column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df), like the following

```
    Column1 Column2 ...
0      1       1    
1    Null      1
.
.
```

I want to plot the count of null values in each column

Currently, I am doing

```py
    df.isnull().sum().plot.bar()
    plt.show()
```

[image: Count of Null Values in each column]

The problem with this is there are about 180 columns and most of them have 0 null values, I want to ignore such columns while plotting.

I tried the following which doesn't seem to work

```py
    df_null = df.loc[: ,df.isnull().sum() > 0]
    df_null.plot()
```

[image: New Plot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If u need NaN count in each column, that have NaN and get bar plot, the next code may help:

```
df.isna().sum()[df.isna().sum()>0].plot(kind='bar')
```

Answer (score 12):

I would like to offer you my foolproof solution that I use in almost every notebook:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot_nas(df: pd.DataFrame):
    if df.isnull().sum().sum() != 0:
        na_df = (df.isnull().sum() / len(df)) * 100      
        na_df = na_df.drop(na_df[na_df == 0].index).sort_values(ascending=False)
        missing_data = pd.DataFrame({'Missing Ratio %' :na_df})
        missing_data.plot(kind = "barh")
        plt.show()
    else:
        print('No NAs found')
plot_nas(df)
```

[image: solution]

You can change the size of the graph as following:

```
plot_width, plot_height = (16,18)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (plot_width,plot_height)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
df_null = df.isnull.sum()
df_null[df_null > 0].to_frame('count').T.plot()
```

Or you mean:

```
df.T[df.isnull().sum() > 0].plot()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this just gives the count of the y-axis and column name on the x-axis, could you edit the answer so that a bar is shown.

Comment: Could you check the code again, this still doesn't work https://i.stack.imgur.com/s06vX.png

Comment: @deadLock Check my edit

Answer (score 0):

Subset the columns with a null into a separate dataframe and then plot that `df` -

`df_with_nulls = df[[col for col in df.columns if df[col].isna().sum() > 0]]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the plot is the same as the second one attached in the question.